# Finding source of manage.py subcommand

Tags: python, django, wagtail, manage.py

I'm new to django and working on a modern django/Wagtail CMS app that is seeded using the command `python manage.py loadfixtures`. It seems like `loaddata` is the more common command, and I'm finding it incredibly difficult to find any documentation on `loadfixtures` at all. Could anyone point me towards the difference? It appears under the `[Core]` section of "available subcommands."

As an aside, I'm essentially trying to dump and seed some static page data for the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`loadfixtures` is not a command that exists as standard on either Django or Wagtail, so it's presumably a custom command that's been added by a developer on your project, or possibly a third-party package you have installed. See [Writing custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) for documentation on how these are created - if you have a 'core' app as part of your project, you may well find the code for the command in `core/management/commands/loadfixtures.py`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'd searched for `'loadfixtures'` but not the filename. Silly me.

Comment: Not silly at all! The person who wrote Django's management commands has regretted the "filename as command" decision for years. :)